# how to select only by date from timestamp column in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table.

[image]

as you can see created_date column is timestamp field. now on selection i want to consider only date value. for e.g if i want to make selection of rows from today i want to do something like:-

```
select * from audit_logs where created_date = '2018-11-28';
```

the above query returns null. is it possible to make selection this way ?

Comment: you can use LIKE instead

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text... Please, use formatted text instead of images the next time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `date()` function

```
select * from audit_logs where date(created_date) = '2018-11-28'
```

Comment: thanks. i didn't knew about this date() function. it is working.

Comment: yes sure, it asks to wait for some minutes before i can accept it.

Comment: @sagarlimbu: it's not really a function. It's a different way to write a [type cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS). It's the same as `created_date::date` or `cast(created_data as date)`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative function is `date_trunc(text, timestamp)`, if you want more flexibility (truncate to hour, for example). Check out the postgres documentation (which is great) for all the date/time functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

You do get a timestamp back instead of date, mind.